# Scala type override

Tags: scala

**EDITED AFTER TWO ANSWERS BELOW**
I am trying to make the following Scala code to compile.

```
  abstract class C {
    type T <: C
    def x(other: T): (T, T)
  }

  class C1 extends C {
    override type T = C1
    override def x(other: C1): (C1, C1) = (this, this)
  }

  def doSthg(cs1 : List[C]) {
    val e1 = cs1(0)
    val e2 = cs1(1)

    e1.x(e2)
  }
```

But fails with the following message:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
type mismatch;  found   : e2.type (with underlying type Chromo[G])  required: e1.C  PI3.sc  /GA/src/org/jts/ga  line 76 Scala Problem
type mismatch;  found   : e2.type (with underlying type org.jts.ga.MI2.C)  required: e1.T   MI2.sc  /GA/src/org/jts/ga  line 18 Scala Problem
```

Any idea?

Basically, I want to define a generic class like C above, and have methods with the right type on a subclass (C1).

All is good until a generic method is called on C in soSthg.

Thanks

**NEW EDIT SECTION**

Thanks v much for your replies.
Looking at the following code, I was hoping to avoid asInstanceOf.

```
  abstract class G[T](val t: T) {
    def ~(): G[T]
  }
  abstract class C[T](val g: List[G[T]]) {
    def x(other: C[T]): (C[T], C[T])
  }

  class G1(override val t: Boolean) extends G[Boolean](t){
    override def ~() = new G1(!t)
  }

  class C1(override val g: List[G1]) extends C[Boolean](g) {
    override def x(other: C[Boolean]): (C[Boolean], C[Boolean]) = {
      val go = other.g.map(e => e.asInstanceOf[G1])
      //val go = other.g
      val nc1 = new C1(go)
      (nc1, nc1) // for demo
    }
  }
```

The signature of x(other: C[Boolean]) is the issue indeed.

This would work:

```
def doSthg2[T <: C](csl : List[T]) { csl(0).x(csl(1)) }
```

How to avoid asInstanceOf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem defining C & C1 as above.  The problem is that you're passing an argument to e1.x that is of type C (not C1) and so violates your C1.x method signature.

As far as the compiler is concerned:

1. You're modelling a type hierarchy rooted at trait/class `C`
2. Inside `doSthg`, the vals `e1` & `e2` are each of some type within the hierarchy.  For e1 & e2, the only things known for sure are that `e1.type` and `e2.type` are each subtypes of `C`.  There's *no* guarantee that `e1` and `e2` are of the same type (or are subtypes of one another) - even though the class hierarchy is very shallow (just one subclass, `C1`).  You could extend by adding new subtypes of `C` in new .class/.jar files at any point in the future (possibly generated from .scala/.java files from this compiler on this machine, or even by a different compiler on a different machine!)
3. You have chosen that your method `C1.x` is not flexible - it's argument must be of type `C1`, not any `C`.  Hence, `e1.x` cannot take an 'arbitrary' `e2 <: C` as argument.

So the compiler is doing the right thing, based on your design decisions.  Solutions:

- allow `C1.x` to take arguments of type `C`
- make doSthg argument `List[C1]` (possibly moving doSthg within C1 at the same time)

Comment: Indeed. Something like this would work: def doSthg2[T <: C](csl : List[T]) {
    csl(0).x(csl(1))
  }

Answer (score 10):

`C1` compiles fine. Note that you could remove `override` keyword here:

```
class C1 extends C {
  type T = C1
  def x(other: C1): (C1, C1) = (this, this) // do you mean (other, this)?
}
```

`doSthg` is just invalid: you can't prove that `e2` is `e1.T`. This works as expected:

```
def doSthg(e1: C)(e2: e1.T) {
  e1.x(e2)
}
```

Or this:

```
abstract class C {
  ...
  def create(): T
}

def doSthg(e1: C) {
  val e2 = e1.create()
  e1.x(e2)
}
```

For your original `doSthg` method `x` should accept any instance of `C`:

```
trait C {
  def x(other: C): (C, C)
}
```